# Google Play Store not showing update button

Tags: android, android-update-app

I have a published my App in Google Play Store with version code 4. I made some changes and changed the version code to 5  and also changed the version name and I published the new version through Google Play Store

I can see the new version published but I'm getting `Open` button Instead of `Update`
I checked couple of old questions and none of them gave me the right answer.

Notes:

- The published APK is signed by Google Play Store
- The older version in my phone was installed from Google Play Store
- If I uninstall the old version, Google Play Store gives me the newer on. But I cant force the users to uninstall and re install

any suggestions?

Comment: Did you change the version number?

Comment: Will, there is `Version Code` and `Version Name`. I don't know about version number, where can I find it?

Comment: After publishing update app to  play store, google takes some time to rollout the update. Check after some time when you get the notification that your update is live.

Comment: I will give it sometime, thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

After about an hour the Google Play Store showed the `Update` button

Thanks guys